# Button to copy to clipboard on Google Earth Pro - HTML

Tags: html, google-earth

I would like to put a button inside a Placemark that is able to copy a text to the clipboard.
I've found this code which works just fine in my browser but it doesn't seem to be working on Google Earth Pro.

It actually generates the button but it does nothing:

[The evidence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbMTK.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" value="House number is 257641" id="myInput">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  // Get the text field
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");

  // Copy the text inside the text field
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
  
  // Alert the copied text
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Do you have any ideas on how it could be done?

Answer (score 0):

Because the `navigator.clipboard.writeText` method returns a promise.
https://javascript.info/promise-basics
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText

```js
function myFunction() {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
    copyText.select();
    copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
    navigator.clipboard
        .writeText(copyText.value)
        .then(() => {
            alert("successfully copied");
        })
        .catch(() => {
            alert("something went wrong");
        });
}
```